# Probability-theory

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Please, I would like some Help about a problem in Probability-theory.
A candy store produces have $10$ different kinds of chocolates, which then are placed in bags.
Each bag should have $30$ chocolates.
How many different bags can the store offers?

I tried to solve it using combinations.
 
Is this correct?
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you want to know the number of possible arrangements  of size $r$(30) from $n$ (10) objects, where the order is not important (chocolate and vanilla is equivalent to vanilla and chocolate) and there's replacement (you can have more than 1 candy of the same type).
The formula you need in this case is 
$${{n+r-1}\choose{r}}$$